# Drawing Simple Triangles in 3D.. Only one shows up on Emulator, on real device - No Triangles

Tags: opengl-es, android-emulator, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

```
    // Front face
    fPyramid[0] = 0.0f; fPyramid[1] = 5.0f; fPyramid[2] = 0.0f;
    fPyramid[3] = -3.0f; fPyramid[4] = 0.0f; fPyramid[5] = 3.0f;
    fPyramid[6] = 3.0f; fPyramid[7] = 0.0f; fPyramid[8] = 3.0f;

    // Left face
    fPyramid[18] = 0.0f; fPyramid[19] = 5.0f; fPyramid[20] = 0.0f;
    fPyramid[21] = -3.0f; fPyramid[22] = 0.0f; fPyramid[23] = -3.0f;
    fPyramid[24] = -3.0f; fPyramid[25] = 0.0f; fPyramid[26] = 3.0f;

    // Back face
    fPyramid[9] = 0.0f; fPyramid[10] = 5.0f; fPyramid[11] = 0.0f;
    fPyramid[12] = 3.0f; fPyramid[13] = 0.0f; fPyramid[14] = -3.0f;
    fPyramid[15] = -3.0f; fPyramid[16] = 0.0f; fPyramid[17] = -3.0f;

    // Right face
    fPyramid[27] = 0.0f; fPyramid[28] = 5.0f; fPyramid[29] = 0.0f;
    fPyramid[30] = 3.0f; fPyramid[31] = 0.0f; fPyramid[32] = 3.0f;
    fPyramid[33] = 3.0f; fPyramid[34] = 0.0f; fPyramid[35] = -3.0f;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        fPyramidColor[i*9] = 1.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+1] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+2] = 0.0f;
        if(i < 2)
        {
            fPyramidColor[i*9+1] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+4] = 1.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+5] = 0.0f;
            fPyramidColor[i*9+2] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+7] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+8] = 1.0f;
        }
        else
        {
            fPyramidColor[i*9+2] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+7] = 1.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+8] = 0.0f;
            fPyramidColor[i*9+1] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+4] = 0.0f; fPyramidColor[i*9+5] = 1.0f;
        }
    }
    ...

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(float), fPyramid, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 36*sizeof(float), fPyramidColor, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    ****************************************************************
    //Shaders
    ****************************************************************
        char vShaderStr[] =
        "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;                                                         \n"
        "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;                                                          \n"
        "attribute vec3 vPosition;                                                              \n"
        "attribute vec3 inColor;                                                                \n"
        "varying vec3 theColor;                                                                 \n"
        "void main()                                                                            \n"
        "{                                                                                      \n"
        "   gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(vPosition, 1.0);                \n"
        "   theColor = inColor;                                                                 \n"
        "}                                                                                      \n";

char fShaderStr[] =
        "varying vec3 theColor;                                                                 \n"
        "void main()                                                                            \n"
        "{                                                                                      \n"
        "   gl_FragColor = vec4(theColor, 1.0);                                                 \n"
        "}                                                                                      \n";


    ****************************************************************
    //in drawframe() function
    ****************************************************************
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[0]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);//0 is or position
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uiVBO[1]);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);//2 is for colors
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);

    int iModelViewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(globalProgramObject, "modelViewMatrix");
    int iProjectionLoc = glGetUniformLocation(globalProgramObject, "projectionMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(iProjectionLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, getPerspectiveMatrixInFloat());

    ESMatrix mModelView = ogmLookAt(0, 15, 40,     0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    ESMatrix mCurrent = ogmRotate(&mModelView, fRotationAngle, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    ogmTranslate(&mCurrent, 0, 13, 35);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(iModelViewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, getCurrentMatrixInFloat(mCurrent));

    //and finally draw arrays
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 12);
```

`fRotationAngle` is changing with 0.01.

this is the code, and the output is

[image]
This is the output on emulator. On real device I do not see anything. Just WHITE screen(changing from black to white is a mental peace!)

I am out of tries. Have tries changing geometry to just 2 triangles, but I get to see only one. What is wrong with this?

Comment: The triangles might simply be out of view.

Comment: @Vallentin, I don't think that is the case, because you see, all X's are between -3.0 - +3.0, Y's between 0.0 - +0.5 and Z's between -3.0 - +3.0. Now, why would only one triangle's coordinates will get special treatment and others will remain out of view?.. Also I have tries moving camera here and there.. but there are no other triangles.

Comment: What version of Android are you using and which device are you trying to run the app on?

Comment: Android Version 4.2.2 and 4.3. Device is Samsung S4(have 4.2.2)

Comment: @Adorn: what do your shaders look like? You use hardcoded attribute indices, how do you assign them? What coordinate transformations do you apply?

Comment: @derhass, please see edited quesion

Answer (score 2):

Your shaders should not compile on ES2. According to the [GLES Shading Language 1.0.17 spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) (which is relevant for ES2.0), there are no `layout` qualifiers, and there is no `in/out` (just like with GLSL <=1.20 on desktop GL), but you have to use `attribute` for vertex shader inputs and `varying` for communication between vertex and fragment shader.

You have to use [`glBindAttribLocation`](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml) before linking the program to assign the attribute indices to your shader inputs (or query the ones the GL assigned if you do not specify them).

As a side note: currently, you try to assign index 1 for the color in the shader, but are using 2 in the client code.

Comment: any example? or just say will this vertex shader be correct?  `glBindAttribLocation(programObject, 0, "vPosition");`
`glBindAttribLocation(programObject, 2, "inColor");` // this is before linking the shader and vertex shader like `char vShaderStr[] =
   "uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;     \n"
   "uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;     \n"
   "vec3 vPosition;        \n"
   "vec3 inColor;         \n"
   "varying vec3 theColor;      \n"
   "void main()         \n"
   "{         \n"
   " gl_Position = projectionMatrix*modelViewMatrix*vec4(inPosition, 1.0); \n"
   "theColor = inColor;  \n"
   "}\n";`
`

Comment: @Adorn: you'd have to use `attribute vec3 vPosition` etc. YOu also have to change the fragment shader to use `varying` instead of `in`.

Comment: ya.. got that.. `varying vec3 theColor` in fragment shader as well. But how do I output color from Fragment shader.?

Comment: @Adorn: reading the spec I linked would tell you that there are builtin special variables like `vec4 gl_FragColor` (or the `vec4 gl_FragData[]` array for the multiple render target case)... ;)

Comment: ok Thanks. Thanks for your help.. was really started to look out for spoon feeding.. thx for "reading the spec" thing

Comment: unfortunately, problem is not yet solved. I rewrote the shaders, but the result is same.

Comment: @Adorn: check the Compile and link status for your shaders. Check the error logs. Check for GL errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42358/discussion-between-adorn-and-derhass)